# CPU usage making multiple SSL client connections Boost.ASIO

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, c++20, boost-asio

I made an SMTPS client class based on Boost.Asio. I'm just wondering what I should expect in terms of CPU usage when sending an email using them. Right now as a stress test I queue up 15 on an io_context and then run it, and the CPU spikes to about 6-8% watching the process through top (I'm on centos7 for this).

Is there any obvious things I should look for in terms of bad design? Is this level of CPU usage a concern? I know boost asio is supposed to very fast and efficient.

Notes about the code:

- uses a new SSL context per client class created
- constructor takes an ip::tcp::socket as arg and use std::move to set the class' socket and then the ssl stream
- all calls are asynchronous. i followed the c++11 boost examples when making this code

I made sure all calls are asynchronous, which I expected to cause low cpu usage

Comment: You're already doing what you should: measure. If you need confirmation, compare with other software perf (e.g. socat, openssl s_client etc)

Comment: You can always post on codereview.se and ask for optimization typs

Answer (score 2):

> uses a new SSL context per client class created

Don't do that - unless you really *need* disparate configuration. Contexts are best shared. In fact, that's exactly why they exist separately.

Consider hardcoding the executor (instead of using the default type-erasing one, `any_io_executor`). There's lots of potential improvements, but nobody can tell without the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! (unfortunately I don't feel comfortable posting the code as it is for work and would encompass multiple files and not just snippets). I figured out a scheme to share SSL contexts and fixed a bunch of bugs. I think sharing the SSL contexts made a big difference. A couple of the bugs involved issues with repeatedly calling async functions (resolve, shutdown, etc.) which probably also helped. Now I am looking at sub 2.5% worst case, although sometimes it doesn't even appear at the top of the process list in "top".

Comment: Nice work. Consider using more reliable tools to measure (operf, callgrind etc). That way you reduce the variance in observations, reducing the need for babysitting many runs and "reading the tea leafs" - believe me I recognize that grind. Ultimately, having application-level telemetry is good to monitor behavior over time.